Are these polynomials the same?
Let $p=2^{127}-1,P,Q\in \mathbb F_p[x]$ with $P(x)=x^2+1$ and $Q(x)=x^2+2$.

Are there some polynomial $H  \in \mathbb F_p[x]$ bijectif on $\mathbb F_p$ with $\forall x \in \mathbb F_p, H(P(x))=Q(H(x))$ ?

I have asked here (*) this question but, no answers.
(*) : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3323185

Every function over a field is a polynomial of high enough degree

Yes, and $H$ does exist ? ${}{}{}$

So it means asking whether $P,Q$, viewed as self-maps of $F_p$, are conjugate (by a permutation).

Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

No, they aren't.
Each of these self-maps $f\in\{P,Q\}$ has a unique point with a unique preimage $\{0\}$. So any such conjugation $u$ has to fix $0$. For both $f$, we have $f^{\circ 2}(0)\neq 0$, so $f^{\circ 3}(0)$ has exactly two  preimages: $f^{\circ 2}(0)$ and its negative. So $u$ has to map $-P^{\circ 2}(0)$ to $-Q^{\circ 2}(0)$. But then one sees that $-P^{\circ 2}(0)$ has two preimages by $P$ while $-Q^{\circ 2}(0)$ has no preimage by $Q$. So there exists no such conjugation.
Precisely: $-P^{\circ 2}(0)=-2$, so $P^{-1}(\{-P^{\circ 2}(0)\})$ is the set of square roots of $-3$, while $-Q^{\circ 2}(0)=-6$, so $Q^{-1}(\{-Q^{\circ 2}(0)\})$ is the set of square roots of $-8$.
Now it's a game using quadratic reciprocity:

$p$ is 3 mod 4, so $-1$ is not a square mod $p$
$p$ is $\pm 1$ mod 8, so $2$ is a square mod $p$.
given this, we see that $-8$ is not a square mod $p$
since both $3$ and $p$ are $-1$ mod 4, $3$ is a square mod $p$ iff $p$ is not a square mod $3$, i.e., if $p$ is $-1$ mod $3$, which is not the case. So $3$ is not a square mod $p$
hence $-3$ is a square mod $p$.

Note that we reach the same conclusion for every $p$ which is $7$ mod $24$.

A variant solution: Suppose there is such an $H$. As $H$ is bijective on $\mathbb F_p$, we get that $P^{\circ m}(x)-x$ and $Q^{\circ m}(x)-x$ have the same number of roots for all $m$ (counted without multiplicities). In particular
\begin{equation}
x^2+x+2 = \frac{P^{\circ 2}(x)-x}{P(x)-x}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
x^2+x+3 = \frac{Q^{\circ 2}(x)-x}{Q(x)-x}
\end{equation}
have the same number of roots. (Note that $P(x)-x$ and $Q(x)-x$ are separable.) The discriminant of these polynomials is $-7$ and $-11$, respectively. But quadratic reciprocity yields the contradiction
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{-7}{p}\right)=1\ne-1=\left(\frac{-11}{p}\right).
\end{equation}
